# qemu simulate xlnx-zcu102 report No 'PCI' bus found

Tags: qemu, qemu-device

qemu version is 7.1.0
I use qemu to simulate xlnx-zcu102. my qemu command is below, it can run OK:
`./qemu-system-aarch64 -M xlnx-zcu102 -smp 4 -m 4G ......`

but, when I add `-device virtio-gpu` or `-device virtio-gpu-device`,
(I added only one device: virtio-gpu)
qemu tell me ERROR like this:
`qemu-system-aarch64: -device virtio-gpu: No 'PCI' bus found for device 'virtio-gpu-pci'`

I don't know how to add a virtio-gpu device to xlnx-zcu102 in qemu command.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add that device to that machine type. The xlnx-zcu102 machine type simulates a piece of real hardware that does not have a PCI bus, and so you cannot plug PCI devices into it. You need to either use a different machine type, or else not use virtio devices.

Comment: I change a machine, use qemu-system-x86_64 -machine q35 it can run with a device virtio-gpu. But, when I use the device "virtio-gpu-gl", qemu tells me ERROR:
qemu-system-x86_64: -device virtio-gpu-gl: opengl is not available.

Actually, I configure the qemu with --enable-sdl --enable-opengl --enable-virglrenderer.

how do i use the device : virtio-gpu-gl ?

thanks

Comment: when I use option ：-device virtio-gpu-gl -display sdl,gl=on. qemu tell me ERROR:

qemu-system-x86_64: ../ui/console-gl.c:105: surface_gl_update_texture: Assertion `gls' failed.

i am confused